# Type MisMatch and The local variable result may not have been initialized

Tags: java

When i run this code i got 2 type of error:

1. The local variable result may not have been initialized
2. type mismatch

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cal_forme {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner calculator =new Scanner(System.in);
    double fnum,snum,result;
    System.out.println("Enter your first num : ");
    fnum =calculator.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter your second num :");
    snum =calculator.nextDouble();
    if (result =fnum + snum) {
        System.out.println("your addition is here" +result); }
        else if (result =fnum - snum) {
            System.out.println("your substraction is here" +result); }

        else {
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
}

}
```

Comment: Hint: initialize the variables e.g. `result = 0.00;`

Comment: if (result *`=`* fnum + snum)

Comment: `if (result =fnum + snum)` what do you want this statement to do? If you want assignment, it can't be a condition, since the returned type is not boolean.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to achieve here. You need to initialize `result` with some initial value like `0.00`.
Also , inside `if` braces you need to have a condition , not an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
if (result =fnum + snum) {
    System.out.println("your addition is here" +result); }
```

The problem with the code *AS WRITTEN* is that the type of the expression `result = fnum + snum` is `double`, but the condition of an `if` statement must have type `boolean`.

That causes the "type mismatch".

The "local variable result may not have been initialized" error *probably* happens because the previous error is confusing the compiler, and it cannot figure out that `result` has been definitely assigned at the point you are trying to use it.

So what is the fix?

Well reading between the lines, my guess is that you are supposed to read a character (e.g. '+' or '-') from the user to tell the calculator what to do.  Then you need to test that character ...

But either way, `if (result = fnum + snum)` is wrong because you need a `boolean`, and `if (result == fnum + snum)` is wrong because `result` has not been initialized ... and it doesn't make a lot of sense given what you are attempting to print.